# how to see files in /dev/sda5 and delete them

Tags: 16.04, boot, dual-boot, partitioning

I'm a new ubuntu user on a ubuntu16.04lts-win10 dual boot. 64gb ram, 1 tb ssd, lenovo p50. 
I had alloted 500gb to each os.

```
  df -i /
    Filesystem       Inodes   IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
    /dev/sda5      28598272 1234421 27363851    5% /

vivek@vivek:~$ sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL
[sudo] password for vivek: 
NAME   FSTYPE   SIZE MOUNTPOINT LABEL
sda           953.9G            
├─sda4 ntfs   453.2G            Windows
├─sda2 ntfs     450M            Recovery
├─sda5 ext4   436.3G /          
├─sda3 vfat     100M /boot/efi  
├─sda1          128M            
└─sda6 swap    63.7G [SWAP]
```

and :

```
 vivek@vivek:~$ sudo fdisk -l
    Disk /dev/sda: 953.9 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
    Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    Disklabel type: gpt
    Disk identifier: blah blah blah blah blah

    Device          Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
    /dev/sda1          34     262177    262144   128M Microsoft reserved
    /dev/sda2      264192    1185791    921600   450M Windows recovery environment
    /dev/sda3     1185792    1390591    204800   100M EFI System
    /dev/sda4     1390592  951830527 950439936 453.2G Microsoft basic data
    /dev/sda5   951830528 1866817535 914987008 436.3G Linux filesystem
    /dev/sda6  1866817536 2000408575 133591040  63.7G Linux swap


Update: looks like somehow sda5 is taking up all my space :(


vivek@vivek:~$ df -Th
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev           devtmpfs   32G     0   32G   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     6.3G  9.4M  6.3G   1% /run
/dev/sda5      ext4      430G  381G   27G  94% /
tmpfs          tmpfs      32G   56M   32G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs     5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs          tmpfs      32G     0   32G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda3      vfat       96M   29M   68M  30% /boot/efi
tmpfs          tmpfs     6.3G   88K  6.3G   1% /run/user/1000
```

How do I view and delete content of /dev/sda5 , because I have no idea how it is 96% full? 
It's ridiculous how my laptop keeps complaining that `device is out of space`

UPDATE after Terrence command `

```
vivek@vivek:~$ sudo du --max-depth 1 / | sort -n
du: cannot access '/run/user/1000/gvfs': Permission denied
du: cannot access '/proc/3360/task/3360/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/3360/task/3360/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/3360/fd/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/3360/fdinfo/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/5444/task/5490/fd/297': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/5444/task/5490/fd/298': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/5444/task/5495/fdinfo/297': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/5444/task/5495/fdinfo/298': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/5444/task/5524/fd/297': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/5444/task/5524/fd/298': No such file or directory
0    /proc
0    /sys
4    /cdrom
4    /lib64
4    /mnt
4    /snap
4    /srv
8    /media
16    /lost+found
996    /dev
3952    /lib32
12724    /sbin
12976    /bin
15736    /etc
26012    /run
38652    /root
173618    /boot
180116    /opt
737740    /lib
1028828    /tmp
11000220    /var
11086764    /usr
19430924    /home
43749306    /
```

Update 2 :
to make things more wierd :

```
vivek@vivek:~$ df
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev            32807352         0  32807352   0% /dev
tmpfs            6566660     25972   6540688   1% /run
/dev/sda5      450182848 427291792         0 100% /
tmpfs           32833300     61784  32771516   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120         4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           32833300         0  32833300   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda3          98304     28994     69310  30% /boot/efi
tmpfs            6566660        76   6566584   1% /run/user/1000
vivek@vivek:~$ df -ih
Filesystem     Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev             7.9M   532  7.9M    1% /dev
tmpfs            7.9M   793  7.9M    1% /run
/dev/sda5         28M  1.2M   27M    5% /
tmpfs            7.9M    64  7.9M    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs            7.9M     5  7.9M    1% /run/lock
tmpfs            7.9M    16  7.9M    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda3           0     0     0     - /boot/efi
tmpfs            7.9M    34  7.9M    1% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: You might want to look at tools like "filelight" to see what is using up all the diskspace.

Comment: I tried instaling `ncdu` and `filelight`. But it says ` No space left on device`. my laptop is literally inching towards becoming a potato.  
what is strange is https://www.diskreport.net/report/65c36aae4a67621be2d2b3fa640539f2/view   here it says only 63 gb used.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo du --max-depth 1 / | sort -n` that will sort the biggest folders to the bottom of the list?  Don't worry as much about `/` being listed last as that is the entire amount, but it will show you the other folders containing large amounts of data.

Comment: ` gksudo baobab
No space left on device`

Comment: @Terrance Pls see updated result. there is some `/` folder eating up all 463gb.

Comment: 43GB is what it shows.  Let me go look and see if I can find a previous question that was right along the lines of this one.

Comment: ok thank you. I referred https://askubuntu.com/questions/727112/give-more-hard-disk-space-to-ubuntu?rq=1 and https://askubuntu.com/questions/871825/add-more-disk-space-for-linux-from-windows-in-a-dual-bootable-machine/871858

Comment: I think one like this https://askubuntu.com/a/74745/231142 might be closer

Comment: Since all of your space is mounted on `/`, `/home` is on `/dev/sda5`. Your `19430924    /home` (or `/home/vivek`) is taking up a lot of space. A better way to install Linux is to have `/home` on its own partition. That said, you could see if some long-running process has an ever-growing file open with `sudo lsof / | awk '{if($7 > 1048576) print $7/1048576 "MB" " " $9 }' | sort -n -u` or check for "deleted", but open files with `sudo lsof / | egrep 'PID|\(deleted\)'`